# TMR0 Inaccurate Result

Tags: pic

I'm fairly new to micro controllers especially the Pic series. I have a question about the TMR0 of the pic16F877A.

I am aware that TMR0 is an 8 bit timer, which takes a total of 256 ticks until an overflow occurs. My configuration runs on a 4MHZ quartz crystal, therefore each tick is equal to 1us. A total time of 256us will cause an overflow keeping in mind the prescaler is chosen to be 1:1.

After simulating this delay by setting bit RB1 equal to (HIGH), a total delay of 265us was measured using proteus 7. Where is this discrepancy coming from? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Code:

```
#include <xc.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

    #pragma config FOSC = HS        
    #pragma config WDTE = OFF      
    #pragma config PWRTE = OFF      
    #pragma config BOREN = OFF      
    #pragma config LVP = ON        
    #pragma config CPD = OFF        
    #pragma config WRT = OFF       
    #pragma config CP = OFF  



void main()
{
    TRISBbits.TRISB1=0;
    PORTBbits.RB1=0;

    TMR0IE=0;
    TMR0IF=0;
    T0SE=0;
    T0CS=0;
    PSA=1;
    TMR0=0;

    while(1)
    {
    while(TMR0IF!=1);
    PORTBbits.RB1=1;
    TMR0IF=0; //I assume it takes 1us
    TMR0=0; // Also 1us?

    while(TMR0IF!=1);
    PORTBbits.RB1=0;
    TMR0IF=0;
    TMR0=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try what happens when you remove the TMR0 = 0? I'm not firm with PICs but the timers I've come across usually start counting from 0 again, resetting it again to 0 would result in loosing some counted clocks and in a longer period.

Comment: Don't forget that the instructions turning the pin HIGH and LOW, as well as the overflow test and loops also take some time.

Comment: Your problem is almost certainly with your TMR0=0; line. When the the timer rolls over and sets the flag, it is then already at 0. You're then resetting it to 0 some time later and so loosing the couple of counts it has already made.

Comment: I took your advice and removed that line. The total delay time is now 255us. Thanks for your help, I thought the TMR0 register had to be cleared after every overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect the discrepancy comes mainly from your "while(TMR0IF != 1)" checks. Even after the interrupt flag is set, you still have to complete the test to see if TMR0IF is 1. This will take several instructions (on the assembly level) which takes time, as well as initializing the timer (no, this will take more than one "tick" to complete) and the instructions required for setting/clearing RB1.

If you want absolute accuracy you really shouldn't be using C as it is much more difficult to account for timing. One line in C could take a dozen instruction cycles. It's much easier to account for the timing if you use ASM (though that's the ONLY time I would ever consider using ASM, personally).

Comment: Would that really increase the period and not just introduce a delay and a jitter (depending on when exactly the test succeeded compared to the first test)?

Comment: The OP said nothing about the period. It would certainly introduce a delay in the turn-on/turn-off timing though.

Comment: Before going ASM, he should see if using an interrupt might fix things up.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I think an interrupt will still give you some delay due to the behind-the-scene calls, unless that's taken care of in the implementation of the interrupt service routine. I never looked at the disassembly of an ISR. Either way, I agree the OP should definitely try an interrupt first to see what happens. Maybe it'll fix it altogether....

Comment: There will certainly be a delay between the timer rollover and the start of the interrupt routine, but it will be fairly deterministic, and anything generated off of it will be periodic at the rollover count, and with little phase noise

Answer (score 1):

You need not reset TMR0 to zero - it will get to maximum count of 255, and on its next clock will wrap back to zero. You have correctly reset the interrupt flag for TMR0 (TMR0IF=0) for every overflow event. Your code should work as you expect if you remove both lines:
TMR0=0;
Your PORTBbits.RB1 output should now toggle every 256 clocks (256 us).

Answer (score 0):

Without bothering to account for every clock tick of every statement, I'll say up front that the use of timers with this requirement for accuracy are best handled with timer interrupts, and not constant polling.  The polling will eat up clock ticks and will additionally create more phase noise than what you want.

Thus, instead of using decision statements and branching code to do things, let the HARDWARE deal with the timing.

Comment: I had to research on how to use interrupts, and to my surprise it actually took 10uS longer than the original attempt. Perhaps its a case of bad programming? Thanks for your reply it helps verify my understand in this situation.

Comment: It's not how *long* it takes, it's how deterministic and repeatable it is.  If you know, for example, that you need to account for the copying over of registers that takes place when the interrupt is called, you preload your timer.  Even if you don't, any behavior the timer drives will have the right period.

Comment: And, yes, there is overhead in using interrupts.  There are registered that need to be stored so that after the interrupt, the stack can be restored.

Comment: Thanks for such an informative comment! You made things far more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should realize that the execution time of code written in C will vary depending on what machine code the compiler generates. You cannot assume that a particular line of code will take 1us just because it only does one operation.

Here is the assembler output of your code, compiled with XC8 V1.37 in 'free' mode:-

```
; while(1)
l19:    
 ; {
 ; TMR0=0;
    bcf status, 5   
    bcf status, 6   
    clrf    (1) 
    goto    l20

 ; while(1)
 l19:   
 ; {
 ; while(TMR0IF!=1);
    goto    l20
 l21:   
 l20:   
    btfss   (90/8),(90)&7
    goto    u11
    goto    u10
 u11:
    goto    l20
 u10:

 l22:   
 ; PORTBbits.RB1=1;
    bcf status, 5   
    bcf status, 6   
    bsf (6),1   

 ; TMR0IF=0;
    bcf (90/8),(90)&7

 l492:  
 ; TMR0=0;
    clrf    (1) 

 ; while(TMR0IF!=1);
    goto    l23
 l24:   
 l23:   
    btfss   (90/8),(90)&7
    goto    u21
    goto    u20
 u21:
    goto    l23
 u20:
 l25:   
  ; PORTBbits.RB1=0;
    bcf status, 5
    bcf status, 6
    bcf (6),1   

  ; TMR0IF=0;
    bcf (90/8),(90)&7

 l494:  
 ; TMR0=0;
    clrf    (1) 
    goto    l20
 l26:
    goto    l20
```

`TMR0IF=0;` and `TMR0=0;` may indeed compile to single machine code instructions, but other statements such as `PORTBbits.RB1=1;` create several instructions. If the time delays involved in setting RB1 both high and low were the same then they would cancel out, but the code is sprinkled with many `goto` instructions which delay the overflow detection.

A hand-crafted assembler program could get closer timing by removing unnecessary code and (if required) adding NOPs to equalize the delays. However there would still be a 2-3us delay due to the time it takes to poll TMR0IF. Using interrupts may reduce jitter, but an adjustment must still be made for interrupt latency and execution time of the code in the ISR.

Finally, clearing Timer0 takes 2 cycles to complete so the total number of cycles to overflow will be 258 not 256. This is documented in the datasheet:-

> In Timer mode, the Timer0 module will increment every instruction
>   cycle (without prescaler). **If the TMR0 register is written, the
>   increment is inhibited for the following two instruction cycles.** The
>   user can work around this by writing an adjusted value to the TMR0
>   register.